# SCROLL_STATE_IDLE can not resolve symbol why?

Tags: android, android-studio

I have implemented this method, as many other tutorial says, but in my case compiler raise error. Why?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    final RecyclerView recList = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.ratingIconList);
    recList.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener(){
                    @Override
                    public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
                        super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);

                        if (newState == SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
                            MainActivity.programmaticScrollEnable = true;
                        }
                    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably, your class does not extend one that has `SCROLL_STATE_IDLE` defined.

Since you appear to be working with `RecyclerView`, perhaps you should be [using `RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html#SCROLL_STATE_IDLE).

Answer (score 0):

Since you are adding a ScrollListener to a ReciclerView, you must reference `SCROLL_STATE_IDLE` as follows:

```
RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE
```

`SCROLL_STATE_IDLE` can be only used as you are doing in a ListView and your OnScrollListener extends `AbsListView.OnScrollListener` (which is not your case).

Change from:

```
if (newState == SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
    MainActivity.programmaticScrollEnable = true;
}
```

To:

```
if (newState == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
    MainActivity.programmaticScrollEnable = true;
}
```

You don't need any import since this constast is member of `ReciclerView` which is already was imported to your project.